# Can I add "firewall rules" to an AWS VPN connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, site-to-site-vpn

i need to connect a couple of customers to an AWS VPC via VPN. requirements:

- no customer may send data (or best: even "see") another customer
- they should only be able to "see" exactly one internal host, preferably only a certain port range.

my question is - is this possible with an AWS VPN gateway & VPN connection? and if yes, how?

cause i read a ton of stuff now and google quite a lot, and i did not find *any* way to assign security groups (or something alike) to an AWS VPN connection. in my book that means "any site-2-site connection allows all traffic", which is the opposite of what i need.

can anybody help me here?

thanks in advance for any information! :)

```
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────┐                    ┌──────────┐
│subnet 1           │         subnet 2│                    │          │
│ ┌──────────┐      │                 │   ┌────────────────┤customer 1│
│ │          │      │must be possible │   │                │          │
│ │server 1  │◄─────┼────┐            │   ▼                └──────────┘
│ │          │      │    │   ip: ┌────┴─────┐ip:                ▲
│ └──────────┘      │    │   int1│    .     │public             │
│                   │    ├───────┤vpn gw    │                   │ must also
│ ┌──────────┐      │    │       │    .     │                 XXX not be
│ │          │      │    │       └────┬─────┘                   │ possible
│ │server 2  │◄─XXX─┤XXX─┘            │   ▲                     │
│ │          │      │must not be      │   │                ┌────┴─────┐
│ └──────────┘      │possible         │   │                │          │
│                   │                 │   └────────────────┤customer 2│
│                   │                 │                    │          │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────┘                    └──────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) is more likely to be suitable than a standard VPN, a standard VPN isn't really made to connect multiple customers. Client VPN works well, though I never tried routing between multiple clients. Be careful with authentication.

If you have to use site to site VPNs, and you have one server per customer I would approach this differently. I'd have a separate subnet / VPN / account per customer and keep things completely separate, so separate VPNs. Share infrastructure can be done with shared VPCs, transit gateway, etc.

Comment: unfortunately the customers all "do" site-2-site VPNs, and so far i think client VPN is structurally different from that (not "just" a different impelementation of top of the very same protocol, so the client does not notice a difference ...). please correct me if I'm wrong, i'm no VPN expert (to maybe state the obvious ) ...

Comment: Read the second paragraph of my answer, which I've tweaked slightly to make it easier to understand.

Comment: hi @tim, sure can do, it's just also a cost issue :) . also AWS limits. basically it's the way we're doing it right now, still feels overkill.

Comment: I don't think you're using AWS VPNs how they're design to be used. One per customer is what I'd do. You might be better off creating an EC2 instance and installing software and doing VPNs that way. In your place I would be rethinking my architecture.

Comment: well if you could guide me to some sources about how it is actually supposed to be used, we both could stop thinking :D

Comment: My answer provides my opinion.